# VBA: Replace function does not work on string...?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I'm getting really confused..this script should parse a selected mail line by line. These mails are of course not always plain text but sometimes formated text. The script worked on plain text files but with mails the replace doesn't work. Why?

The data in the mail is separated by blanks (from 1 to 5)
i.e.

```
     24 month
5/1 5/2 5/3 5/4
20    50    30    20
```

However when I step through the code the replace doesn't have any effect and the string length remains the same.

Here's part of my parsing script:

```
Dim varCurrentLine As Variant
Dim strCurrentLine As String
Dim astrLines() As String
Dim astrCurrentLine() As String

astrLines = Split(myMail.Body, vbCrLf)

For Each varCurrentLine In astrLines
    strCurrentLine = CStr(varCurrentLine)

    If (InStr(1, strCurrentLine, "24 Month")) Then boolStartParsing = True

    If (boolStartParsing) Then
        strCurrentLine = Replace(strCurrentLine, "         ", " ")
        strCurrentLine = Replace(strCurrentLine, "        ", " ")
        strCurrentLine = Replace(strCurrentLine, "       ", " ")
        strCurrentLine = Replace(strCurrentLine, "      ", " ")
        strCurrentLine = Replace(strCurrentLine, "     ", " ")
        strCurrentLine = Replace(strCurrentLine, "    ", " ")
        strCurrentLine = Replace(strCurrentLine, "   ", " ")
        strCurrentLine = Replace(strCurrentLine, "  ", " ")

        If (Len(strCurrentLine) > 0) Then
            astrCurrentLine = Split(strCurrentLine, " ")

            'Parsin code omitted

        End If
    End If
Next varCurrentLine
```

Answer (score 0):

That certainly makes me think that the spaces you have used to compare the spaces in the mail text do not match.

Comment: Yeah same here..but how can spaces be any different?! :-)

Comment: When you say plain text and formatted text, the spaces may differ depending on the character set.

Comment: soo do you have any advice what I can do? I really have no clue at the moment

Comment: Ahh, I cannot find anything that really mentions that spaces could be different, but may be [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397148/vbscript-replace-all-spaces) can give some idea.

Answer (score 0):

Found this link on Google:

http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/join.htm#trimall

There's a chance that your "spaces" may be "non breaking space characters", which are `CHR(160)` in VBA.

You can also use a `while` loop to clean up your code:

```
While InStr(strCurrentLine, Chr(32) & Chr(32)) > 0 _
    Or InStr(strCurrentLine, Chr(160) & Chr(160)) > 0

    strCurrentLine = Replace(strCurrentLine, Chr(32) & Chr(32), Chr(32))
    strCurrentLine = Replace(strCurrentLine, Chr(160) & Chr(160), Chr(32))
Wend
```